# Get client SSL certificate details in Firebase Cloud Function endpoint

Tags: node.js, sockets, https, google-cloud-functions, ssl-certificate

In a Firebase function that acts as a webhook, I'd like to read the details of the client SSL certificate. According to the docs,

> With HTTPS support, use request.socket.getPeerCertificate() to obtain
> the client's authentication details.

The following however does not work because the `getPeerCertificate` method is undefined in `onRequest`'s `req.socket`

```
export const myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  conosle.log(req.socket.getPeerCertificate());
});
```

I tried the following workaround but it produced an empty result, perhaps meaning the certificate is not being sent even though it is supposed to be, or that something else is wrong

```
import { TLSSocket } from "tls";

export const myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const socket = new TLSSocket(req.socket, { requestCert: true });
  console.log(socket.getPeerCertificate());
});
```

As I understand the `getPeerCertificate` method is available when creating an https server with the `https` package but is there not a built-in way in `functions.https` to achieve this? I'm assuming the certificate will be taken from the request and there is no need to provide a local copy.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current implementation of Firebase Cloud Functions does not provide a direct way to access the client SSL certificate details in the onRequest event. I would highly suggest to file a feature request in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/). However, there's no ETA for it.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so the community can benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer:

Unfortunately, the current implementation of Firebase Cloud Functions does not provide a direct way to access the client SSL certificate details in the onRequest event. I would highly suggest to file a feature request in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/). However, there's no ETA for it.